# notepad++ cursor on all marked items

Tags: notepad++

I want to add cursor on all marked text in notepad++?
How to select all marked items and edit at once?
I want to add `"}}"` on all marked (at the end of marked)
change `**{{!COL1**` to `**{{!col1}}**` and so on....

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form ATTR=ID:url CONTENT={{!**COL1**
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:form ATTR=ID:limit CONTENT=%

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form ATTR=ID:url CONTENT={{!**COL2**
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:form ATTR=ID:limit CONTENT=%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the search/replace functionality.

If you like to add `}}` to each match, then you have to play around with the regular expressions, e.g. search for `{{COL(\d+)` and replace with `{{col\1}}`.
Be sure to set search mode to `Regular expression`.

The `\d+` will match 'one or more digits'.

Using `()` in the search term will introduce backtracking; each group of `()`s can be referenced to by `\<number>` in the replace section.

More info on http://markantoniou.blogspot.nl/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html.

Comment: COL1 COL2 COL3 ... COL100 to COL1}} COL2}} ... COL100}}

Comment: @AakashPal: see my edits. You will want to play around with regular expressions for the digits, e.g. `(\d+)` ("one digit or more").

Comment: not working when i find COL(\d) and replace with COL(\d)}} then result all changed to COLd}} i dont want to change 1,2,3... with d

Comment: Very Thanks Saex and stackoverflow